# Why are there extra characters in the output of the following C code?

Tags: arrays, c, string, io, char

I have file **statistics.txt** where is the following data:

```
Mark = 100
Andy = 200
```

Then, I wrote this code:

```
FILE *file_statistics_reading = fopen("statistics.txt", "r");

char line[1024];
int n = 0;
char player[10];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_statistics_reading) != NULL) {
    n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if ((line[i] > 'A') && (line[i] < 'z')) {
            player[n] = line[i];
            n = n + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", player);
}

fclose(file_statistics_reading);
```

I want to extract the names of the players from the text file and print them out, but the output looks like this:

```
Mark╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
Andy╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You need to NUL terminate the array to make it a valid string. `player[n] = '\0';` before the `printf`. Of course you should also increase the `player` size to ensure it can always fit the NUL.

Comment: Strings in C aren't just arrays of characters, they're *null-terminated* arrays of characters.  When you let the compiler construct a string for you by mentioning it in source code, it takes care of appending the null character for you.  When you let most C functions create a string for you (like `fgets` or `scanf` with `%s`), they take care of appending the null character for you.  But when you build a string yourself, one character at a time, like you're doing here, it's your responsibility to add the null character yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- You forgot to set a null terminator after the name in `player`, which explains the random bytes in the output. `player` is an automatic array: its contents are indeterminate at creation time.
- You should make `player` one byte longer.
- The test for letters is incorrect: `'A'` and `'z'` will cause the loop to stop because you use `>` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=`
- Depending on the character set, some non letter bytes will get printed, such as `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` and `` ` `` for ASCII. You should use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`.
- If multiple words appear in the line, the letters in the first 10 bytes, as a single blob for all lines. Separate the output with newlines.
- You do not check for the end of line, so 10 bytes are tested even by reading beyond the end of line, whose contents are indeterminate.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_players(void) {
    char line[1024];
    FILE *file_statistics_reading = fopen("statistics.txt", "r");
    
    if (file_statistics_reading == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open statistics.txt");
        return;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_statistics_reading) != NULL) {
        char player[11];
        size_t n = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; n < sizeof(player) - 1 && line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (isalpha((unsigned char)line[i]) {
                player[n++] = line[i];
            }
        }
        player[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", player);
    }
    fclose(file_statistics_reading);
}
```

Here is an alternative approach to print the first word from the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_players(void) {
    char line[1024];
    FILE *file_statistics_reading = fopen("statistics.txt", "r");
    const char *letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
    if (file_statistics_reading == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open statistics.txt");
        return;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_statistics_reading) != NULL) {
        int start = strcspn(line, letters);       // skip non letters
        int len = strspn(line + start, letters);  // count letters in word
        printf("%.*s\n", len, line + start);
    }
    fclose(file_statistics_reading);
}
```